# cakephp 2.2 Acl not working(groups)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

im going through http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html <--- this tutorial and guess what? ;) it doesnt work, im Using cakephp 2.2.2... i get next error

> Undefined index: id [CORE/Cake/Model/AclNode.php, line 140]
>
> AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by
> "Array ( [Aro0.model] => User [Aro0.foreign_key] => )
> " Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

this error is becouse i dont get my group_id in my User model

```
public function bindNode($user) {
            return array('model' => 'Groups', 'foreign_key' => $user['Users']['groups_id']);
        }
```

So in this function $user var contains only username and password... and no group_id's

Please help guys...

Answer (score 1):

Model name must be singular.

```
'model' => 'Group'
$user['Users']['group_id'] //in your DB, put "group_id" to, not "groups_id"
```

Make sure that the Model you've created is "Group". :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this problem. Tracing the code back the issue was that my model was called 'AdminUser' and not the default, 'User'. Altering the userModel setting solved it for me.

```
public $components = array(
    'Acl', 
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array(
            'Actions' => array(
                'actionPath' => 'controllers',
                'userModel' => 'AdminUser'
            )
        )
    ), 
    'Session'
);
```

Looking at your bindNode method it looks like your using a model named 'Users' rather than 'User' so setting the userModel to 'Users' might do the trick.

I hope that helps,
Pete